# How to do mathematical operations{eg. diff()} in multiple columns of the DataFrame and save the result in the same DataFrame as a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a data frame like this:

```
df=
    p1  v1  p2  v2  p3  v3  p4  v4  p5  v5  p6  v6
0   3   6   5   8   4   4   8   4   9   6   0   0
1   5   0   5   9   0   8   8   5   5   2   2   9
2   6   9   8   6   9   9   9   2   8   4   2   6
3   4   1   8   0   5   9   0   2   1   2   4   8
4   1   4   8   1   3   1   4   9   6   2   6   7
5   5   4   6   5   5   2   3   0   5   5   6   4
6   4   4   9   0   2   1   7   0   1   0   8   8
7   9   1   7   3   5   4   4   4   8   9   3   8
8   1   5   0   5   4   3   6   5   2   3   1   4
9   9   1   7   6   5   3   6   8   8   4   7   5
10  1   6   5   8   2   5   1   5   3   4   5   8
11  8   7   6   6   9   3   5   5   9   7   6   7
```

**p** and **v** are certain parameters measured for different samples (e.g. 1, 2, 3..etc.). Now I want to multiply all the columns of **"p_"** by a number **and** use `diff()` on all the columns of **"v_"** to subtracting the subsequent rows of that column.

I want to save the results in the same DataFrame using the corresponding samples name and the first letter of mathematical operation, like **Dv1**, **Dv2** for output of `df. diff('v1'), df.diff('v2')` and etc. Similarly, for columns of **p**, it would be like **Mp1**.

Manually for each column, I can do the operation and save the results, but it's tedious(as the number of samples is very high), so I want to automate it using conditions like for loop.

Any suggestion to do mathematical operations(subtracting, multiplying or dividing) in multiple columns of the pandas' DataFrame and save the result in the same DataFrame as a new column using a combination of column name and mathematical operation name.

New DataFrame should look like this `p1 Mp1 v1 DV1 p2 Mp2 v2 Dv2 p3 Mp3 v3 Dv3.......` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

str_data = """
p1,v1,p2,v2,p3,v3,p4,v4,p5,v5,p6,v6
3,6,5,8,4,4,8,4,9,6,0,0
5,0,5,9,0,8,8,5,5,2,2,9
6,9,8,6,9,9,9,2,8,4,2,6
4,1,8,0,5,9,0,2,1,2,4,8
1,4,8,1,3,1,4,9,6,2,6,7
5,4,6,5,5,2,3,0,5,5,6,4
4,4,9,0,2,1,7,0,1,0,8,8
9,1,7,3,5,4,4,4,8,9,3,8
1,5,0,5,4,3,6,5,2,3,1,4
9,1,7,6,5,3,6,8,8,4,7,5
1,6,5,8,2,5,1,5,3,4,5,8
8,7,6,6,9,3,5,5,9,7,6,7
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(str_data))


#Doing this in case you have a pN, but not a vN, or vice versa to avoid errors
p_samples = [int(c[1:]) for c in df.columns if c.startswith('p')]
v_samples = [int(c[1:]) for c in df.columns if c.startswith('v')]
samples = set(p_samples).intersection(v_samples)
samples = sorted(list(samples))

data = {}
mult_num = 7 #not sure what you want to multiply by

for sample in samples:
    p_col = 'p{}'.format(sample)
    v_col = 'v{}'.format(sample)
    
    Mp_col = 'Mp{}'.format(sample)
    Dv_col = 'Dv{}'.format(sample)
    
    data[p_col] = df[p_col]
    data[Mp_col] = mult_num*df[p_col]
    data[v_col] = df[v_col]
    data[Dv_col] = df[v_col].diff()
    
    
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(new_df)
```

Comment: thank you for your help and contribution. Your code run perfectly for sample data, but as you have first changed data into str data using a `multiline string quote` `""" """`, I find it difficult to convert big data with many rows and columns into str data. I want to know how to convert a big dataframe into str data.

Comment: sorry I should have explained in the code, but I'm just using the str_data to create a dataframe from your table for this example. You already have the dataframe in memory some other way, something like pd.read_csv? You don't have to mess with the str_data that's just so I can get the df since I don't have the same files as you

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thanks for your reply and support, Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```py
# Find all columns that starts with p and followed by a number
p = df.columns[df.columns.str.match('p\d')]

# Find all columns that starts with v and followed by a number
v = df.columns[df.columns.str.match('v\d')]

# Multiply the p columns by 2
mp = df[p].mul(2).add_prefix('M')

# Take a diff of the v columns
dv = df[v].diff().add_prefix('D')

# The display order of the columns
cols = [f'{j}{i}' for i in range(1,7) for j in ['p', 'Mp', 'v', 'Dv']]

# The final result
final = pd.concat([df, mp, dv], axis=1)[cols]
```

Comment: Thank You very much for your valuable contribution and support. Since my DataFrame has so many columns therefore to select the range  I used `range(1,len(p)+1)`; is there any better way to do this?